# C# File Already Exists Error

Tags: c#, exception, io, ide

I keep on getting this error from every single IDE I use for C#.
Not once have I managed to run any code from any IDE related to any Microsoft based language.

This is really pissing me off and there are apparently no reported occurrences of this in history according to google.

I'm using MonoDevelopment's C# IDE, I also get this error with any Visual Studio IDE's.

Error log from MonoDevelopments IDE: http://pastebin.com/c01QuZYx
Any time I try to run or debug a project it just hangs for hours and eventually it'll die with a IOException "File Already Exists".
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOf3R.png

Comment: You haven't really given us much to go on here... what *exact* error are you getting in Visual Studio? (I would try just plain Visual Studio, no Xamarin, no Mono, and just a console app.)

Comment: I've already tried both IDE's and it's the exact same result, what more do you need? Did you even read what I said?
Also, this is the error: http://i.imgur.com/u5x2Ppk.png Any IDE spews that at me after a while of it hanging while trying to run my project.

Comment: This is probably not the IDE's fault - Have you checked file/folder permissions and tried compiling your project from the command line instead?

Comment: Do you have some form of this application already running? Lynxaa, don't take your frustration out on those that try to help format your question

Comment: Please give more information about the environment you're using. The log shows you're using MonoDevelop and Xamarin for Android? It seems like the error is there somehow. Which other IDEs have you tried?

Comment: And what type of app are you building? I suggested just building a plain console app in VS without *anything* mono-related involved. Have you tried that?

Comment: I've tried Visual Studio 2013 for Desktop and Xamarin Studios. Both with C#.
Every file on my hard drive has read and write permissions, my user has full administration rights.
Sorry for the frustration but this has really gotten the best of me, I've never gotten anything like this before and the lack of documentation on this problem blows my mind.

Comment: What is your project's name? Also, try to use [ProcMon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to try and identify exactly what file already exists, from there you can determine what is causing the issue

Comment: Bernd, http://i.imgur.com/0ekGXWf.png this is the only thing I could find that's related to the IDE.

Comment: Remove all the non-default filters from ProcMon, then let it run and throw the exception, start searching for 'Permission denied', not just specific to the IDE, somewhere it should show up where it is trying to write to a file. If you can't find any of that, look for the project's own files being written and maybe getting errors while writting

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wQ8fljr.png http://i.imgur.com/7iUza4r.png

Answer (score 0):

Disregard this.
I'll have to take another crack at C# once I swap to Windows 8 since the error seems to be OS & User related with READ/WRITE permissions being all jacked up.

With the amount of junk Microsoft installs along side their SDK's and all their other programs all these errors came as no surprise, my programs list is completely full of junk from Microsoft that just slows down my computer.